# Why is my CommandParameter null when I have the Path as SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So I am trying to pass the `SelectedItem` as a parameter so that I can make use of the data that is bound to it.

Essentially I want to open a `MessageBox` and display the `Name` property of the User that is bound that item.

This is my xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardViewModel.Users}"
                          dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                          dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
                          dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultEffectDataTemplate="True">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:UserCard>
                            <controls:UserCard.ContextMenu>
                                <!-- Bind the DataContext of the CM to the DataContext that's bound to the RootObject-->
                                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding DataContext, Source={local:RootObject}}">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Edit"
                                              Command="{Binding CardViewModel.EditUser}" 
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},
                                              Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </controls:UserCard.ContextMenu>
                        </controls:UserCard>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
```

The command works fine everything is bound just fine besides that when I click the `MenuItem` and it fires the command, I put a breakpoint where the action is and it shows the parameter as `null` I am suspecting that it's me who is binding it wrong.

```
public void DisplayEditUser(object user)
{
    if (user != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` wasn't the `ItemsControl` but the `UserCard`, so binding source resolving will absolutely fail. To solve it, you need to bind `ItemsControl.SelectedItem` to one property of `UserCard` such as `Tag` as a relay.

```
<controls:UserCard Tag="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}">

CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
```